# Facebook SDK Authorization is not working in iOS9?

Tags: ios9, facebook-sdk-4.0

I integrated 4.4.0 FBSDK. I am able to get accessToken till version of iOS 8.x.
But in iOS 9 the request is cancelled, not able to get accesstoken. I just followed Whitelist Facebook Servers for Network Requests(ios9 docs from developers.facebook.com). Cany any one guide me in correct way. 
- With Gratitude.

Comment: Finally it is working by set this (options[@"UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"]) in AppDelegate.m,                                                                                               - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application 
    openURL:url sourceApplication:options[@"UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"]   annotation:nil]; 
 }

Comment: You should post that as the answer for the issue and accept it. You could format the code properly then :)